# How do I concatenate multiple lines in a cell with a ';' in Google sheet OR excel?

Tags: excel, google-sheets

In a cell, there are multiple line of strings. I would like to combine them into a single line where each strong is connected with a semi colon.

So this:
String 1
String 2
String 3

Turns into this:
String 1;String 2;String 3

[image]

The column has over 200 cells like this in my spreadsheet. Is there a way to select that entire column and apply a formula to get what I need on all of them?

I tried just doing it manually. But since there are over 200 cells like this, it will take forever.

Comment: In Column N, try `=SUBSTITUTE(M2,CHAR(10),";")`

Comment: Google Sheets and Microsoft Excel have different feature sets. The [google-sheets] tag description explicitly states _"Do NOT use with [excel]"_ and the [excel] tag description explicitly states _"Do NOT use with other spreadsheet software like [google-sheets]."_ Choose one platform and edit tags appropriately.

Answer (score 0):

In google sheets, You can use regex replace like this.
If your text is in A1
This takes all the new line code (\n) and replaces it with (;)

=REGEXREPLACE(A1,"\n",";")

I have found that the CHAR(10) method does not work for me.

Cheers Mads